# How to find zone of image?

Tags: machine-learning, python

[image: ow]

Hello.!
I have been working on a gujrati handwritten dataset to identify character using kNN. 
i'm not able to find the zone of image like above in python.
please help me..!!

Comment: what do you mean by zone?

Comment: zone means we can divided image into N*M zone